# Is BitLocker safe to use on SSDs and can't we unlock the drive on other Operating Systems?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, encryption, bitlocker

I am already using BitLocker and have already encrypted my PC SSD and HDD and even thinking of encrypting all my external drives with BitLocker. But today I read this [article](https://diskcryptor.org/why-not-bitlocker/) from [DiskCryptor](https://diskcryptor.org/) and I was confused about the things it pointed out. Such as,

1. BitLocker does not really care for security.
2. Self-encrypting deception.
3. TPMs can’t be trusted.
4. The operating system is not aware of the operation wear leveling in SSDs.
5. Has poor compatibility with other operating systems. (This is from another article)

Are those true? This is 2023 now and isn't those fixed now? And will this cause damages or issues for the SSDs? Should I move to another alternative disk encryption solution?

Comment: Q1: Do I need disk encryption?

Comment: ANY disk encryption method is dangerous - if any problem arrives you might be in the position of locking your data and throwing away the key. Read all the sob stories on our site.

Comment: If you're concerned about securing some files with PII, such as financial and medical records, you might be better served by encrypting a *folder*, or password-protecting a Zip archive, rather than the whole drive. There are various free and commercial tools to encrypt, such as 7-Zip (see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100650/how-secure-is-7z-encryption) and VeraCrypt. *Caveat emptor*

Comment: “ Should I move to another alternative disk encryption solution?” What are your concerns? Do you really have data that is at risk of being discovered if unencrypted? All encryption holds a risk since the data needs to be decrypted at some point to be used.

Comment: That's not an article. It's advertising. Some points are sort-of valid but others aren't. I think, overall, it squarely fits the category "FUD".

Comment: BitLocker is perfectly safe to use on all storage devices. BitLocker also provides perfectly fine encryption. There is no truth to that article, except perhaps, the lack of Linux compatibility with regards to BitLocker.

Comment: That "article" and you yourself are showing strong bias while trying (and failing) to appear neutral. The "Self-encrypting deception" (as you put it) is a failure in the self encrypting drives, not Microsoft, and Microsoft's only fault is in being naive and trusting the drive manufacturer to have done their job properly. When informed of the problem they correctly stopped trusting manufacturers to do their job. Bitlocker may be proprietary, but that is no reason to lose objectivity and just assume that because you do not have the source code that it is forever tainted.

Comment: BitLocker has been a feature since Windows 7 Ultimate. Since that time there hasn’t been any proof of any substantial weaknesses that exist in the encryption. In fact over the years the strength of the encryption has only increased. You know what had a weakness, enough of them, that all developed stopped by the original team? TrueCrypt, were those weaknesses addressed by the team behind VeraCrypt, absolutely, my point there isn’t any real evidence that BitLocker cannot be trusted.

Comment: “Therefor an obvious backdoor in Windows, like intentionally sending keys from a 3rd party encryption tool to MSFT, is highly unlikely as this could be found out, especially if it happens on every windows system and, could not be plausibly denied by MSFT.” - **Whomever wrote this bold face lie should be exiled off the internet.**

Comment: Any explanation for the downvotes? It's a good question IMO. OP did their research and asked about the part that was beyond their understanding. That's more effort put into it than into half of the questions on this website, and they usually don't get downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: @gronostaj - The author found a random rant, got concerned it was based on reality, and asked a question. They just provided a link. Research wasn’t involved

Comment: @Ramhound Finding that random rant _is_ research. Asking even basic questions is allowed as long as you attempt to find the answer on your own first. This question demonstrates effort: OP was researching whether Bitlocker is secure and they found this. It's well-written and sounds plausible unless you have higher-than-average knowledge about this topic.  OP couldn't assess how accurate this article is, so they asked. This is what Super User is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no TL;DR. Security is a complex topic and there's no one-size-fits-all solution. Nothing is simply *secure* - you have to specify *secure against what*.

Security has three aspects - the "CIA" triad: **C**onfidentiality, **I**ntegrity, **A**vailability. Full disk encryption will make extracting data from your drive harder for everyone, including data recovery specialists when your motherboard dies. This means that confidentiality is increased, but integrity and availability are reduced. (Unless you have good backups - and you should, and since you need encryption on your hard drive, those may have to be encrypted too.)

Now, comments on the points of the article you've linked:

## "Self-encrypting deception"

Summary of the argument: Bitlocker would by default use drive's self-encryption capabilities in older Windows versions, if such features are available. Some drives were shown to have weak built-in encryption, ergo making Bitlocker vulnerable.

This is true, but not necessarily a problem.

Say you've smashed your display and you drop your laptop at your nearest Questionable Laptop Repairs shop to have it replaced. You have it set up with Bitlocker based on self-encryption and your drive's encryption is weak. How much time and money are Questionable Laptop Repairs' technicians going to spend to see your private photos?

If you're Edward Snowden and your adversaries are a bit more determined, then this is a problem. But this is just the default setting - you can turn it off and make Bitlocker rely on its own encryption, which is AES-XTS, the industry standard for full disk encryption. In the past Bitlocker also used Microsoft's own "Elephant" diffuser, but was removed at some point. I don't know if Bitlocker's AES-XTS implementation was ever audited and if so, if any red flags were raised. I haven't heard any complaints from implementors of open-source Bitlocker re-implementations for Linux, dislocker and cryptsetup, too. I'm not a professional though and I'm not spending my days researching full disk encryption. And you shouldn't rely on anonymous internet strangers' opinions anyway, Mr. Snowden.

## "TPMs can’t be trusted"

Summary of the argument: Bitlocker will by default use TPM for convenient key storage and components of the PC platform that implement TPM have had vulnerabilities in the past.

This is essentially the same argument, but for TPMs. Again: this is true, but not necessarily a problem. TPM exploit of this kind would probably be worth millions of dollars and if someone has it, it's probably some government and they don't want to burn it unless they're really mad at you.

And once again, this is just the default setting. You always have an option to change it and type your encryption password manually on boot.

## "The operating system is not aware of the operation wear levelling in SSDs"

Summary of the argument: By default Windows will sometimes pause encryption and dump the encryption password to the disk, in plaintext. Even if it's erased afterwards, it will be recoverable on SSDs due to wear leveling.

Same thing for the 3rd time. Factually accurate. Probably not a concern.

Recovering the plaintext password will require specialized equipment, knowledge and skills. The equipment is not prohibitively expensive, but if you're not a data recovery expert, you won't have it. Neither will Questionable Laptop Repairs or the random person who found your lost laptop in the parking lot. Same with the skill and knowledge.

If you'd rather not have it on disk at all, disable it.

## "BitLocker uploades your recovery keys to the cloud without asking"

Do I have to type the same thing again? Just turn it off.

## "Has poor compatibility with other operating systems"

It's now integrated into cryptsetup, the standard disk encryption utility on Linux.